# What is loose philosophy and what is dense philosophy. What is the difference?

Tags: ethics

I am doing a project for my History class, but it is asking me what kind of philosophy (loose or dense) is being expressed in the image.

[image]

Comment: Don't know what the terms mean and I write in philosophy for a living. Did you get them from a textbook or have someone supply definitions? (best guess I've got is that William James said something about "hard" and "soft" philosophy or thought).

Answer (score 1):

The only mention of "loose" and "dense" philosophy that I have run across is within Rosicrucian Philosophy where the following distinction is applied:

'... humanity today is divided into two classes - those in whom the connection between the vitai body and the dense body is very close and another class where the connection is more loose."

*In summary* -
The dense class is engaged in more material pursuits.
The loose class is engaged in more spiritual pursuits.

I realize that many may not take Rosicrucian Philosophy seriously and perceive it as being esoteric.  But it is the only place where the terms "dense" and "loose" seem to appear (at least in my experience).

Accepting this, I would say the image expresses "dense" philosophy.